# Issue while installing angular-route.d.ts

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-routing, typescript-typings

I am using command   `typings install  angular-route --save -global`
To install `angular-route`. But it is showing this error. Help me to resolve this error.

```
typings ERR! message Unable to find "angular-route" ("npm") in the registry.
typings ERR! message However, we found "angular-route" for 1 other source: "dt"
typings ERR! message You can install these using the "source" option.
typings ERR! message We could use your help adding these typings to the registry: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/angular-route/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200

typings ERR! cwd /Users/sun/enclarity-ui
typings ERR! system Darwin 13.3.0
typings ERR! command "node" "/Users/sun/.nvm/versions/node/v0.12.15/bin/typings" "install" "angular-route" "--save" "-global"
typings ERR! node -v v0.12.15
typings ERR! typings -v 1.3.2

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

This what I get when I search

```
typings search  angular-route
Viewing 2 of 2

NAME                           SOURCE HOMEPAGE             DESCRIPTION VERSIONS UPDATED                 
angular-route                  dt     http://angularjs.org             1        2016-03-17T12:06:54.000Z
angularjs/legacy/angular-route dt     http://angularjs.org             1        2016-03-17T12:06:54.000Z
```

**Edit:** I am using angular 1.5

Comment: i think its typings install dt~angular-route --save -global

Comment: Okay I will try this now

Comment: `typings install dt~angular-route --save --global` note **dt~** and **--global**

Comment: @AlekseyL. thanks it worked.

Comment: @AlekseyL. you can asnwer this. I will mark it as asnwered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `typings install dt~angular-route --save --global`

Note **dt~**(typings source DefinitelyTyped) and **--global**

More info [here](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/commands.md)